# Bat | Как запустить команду не дожидаясь завершения предыдущей?

Tags: windows, bat

Хочу сделать bat файл для запуска нескольких программ.

Щас у меня вот такой код:

```
"D:\Programs\CLion 2020.1\bin\clion64.exe";
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
exit;
```

Но при запуске у меня запускается clion, а хром нет. Если поменять очередь, то все норм, но cmd не закрывается. Вообщем мне как-то нужно сделать, чтобы cmd не запускалась, а запускались просто 2 или более программы.

Ответ для Alexey R.:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ничего не запускается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первым делом нужно открыть директорию с программой, а уже затем запустить ее командой start. Директория открывается командой cd

В итоге ваш код должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
@echo off
cd "D:\Programs\CLion 2020.1\bin"
start clion64.exe
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
start chrome.exe
exit
```

Comment: А как можно передать в start файл в названии которого есть пробелы?

Comment: Я запускаю обычно в одну строчку, то есть без "start" и "cd":

 `"D:\CC games\Just game.exe"`

При этом обязательно нужны кавычки

Comment: Но у меня так не работает.

Comment: Что за бред? о_О Уже давным-давно никто не запускает программы из их собственного каталога.

Comment: @Данил если не трудно, скинь свой код, для запуска приложения с пробелом в названии. Мне интересно в чем может быть проблема

Comment: @Qwertiy сейчас наткнулся на старый ответ и на ваш комментарий по поводу того, что "Уже давным-давно никто не запускает программы из их собственного каталога". А каким образом их тогда еще запускать? Я с `.bat` и `cmd` много не работал, поэтому единственное, что приходит в голову — добавить путь в переменную среды или закинуть "ярлык" запуска в папку `C:\Windows\System32`. Но, разве не проще один раз указать полный путь до каталога и запускать из него? Как еще можно запустить программу не из каталога и почему так уже давным-давно никто не делает?

Comment: @denisnumb, посмотрел внимательнее. Скорее всего, я имел в виду, что большинство программ приспособлены к тому, что текущий каталог может быть любым. Тем более, даже окно открытия файла меняет текущий каталог. Т. е., вероятно, я написал комментарий исходя из предположения, что cd не решает проблему ожидания завершения. Тем не менее, если сравнить твой ответ и мой, то cd в твоём ответе позволяет не использовать кавычки при указании запускаемой программы в start, который, в случае наличия аргумента в кавычках, рассматривает его как заголовок, а не как программу.

Comment: @denisnumb, т. е. твой ответ всё же верный, но не по той причине, которая сперва бросается в глаза (сделать cd перед вызовом), а как бы из-за побочного эффекта (cd оставляет имя без пробелов и отпадает необходимость ставить кавычки). Ну как-то так, по крайней мере, это лучшее, что я могу ответить, потому что вспомнить, что я тогда имел в виду, уже не получается. Ну и держи плюсик.

Comment: @Qwertiy понял, спасибо :)

Comment: Команда CD сама по себе не меняет диски. Для этого её нужно запускать с опцией /D.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно первым параметром указать заголовок - можно пустой:

```
start "" "ping" 8.8.8.8 -n 10
start "" "ping" localhost -n 10
```

В случае из вопроса это будет:

```
start "" "D:\Programs\CLion 2020.1\bin\clion64.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Comment: Зачем первые кавычки?

Comment: @eri, заголовок. Если первый параметр start окажется в кавычках, то его будут рассматривать как заголовок. Соответственно, надо либо запускаемую программу писать без кавычек (что не всегда возможно), либо докинуть ему параметр с пустой (а можно и не пустой) строкой, чтобы он его сжевал и запустил что надо.

Comment: Как в `execv()`.  Я бы в пример привёл с заголовком. Например "ping1" и "ping2"

Comment: @eri, ну в принципе можно приделать заголовки, но у автора в вопросе графические проги, так что там от заголовка никакого смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Qwertiy, помогло.

Мне нужно было решить 2 задачи. Запустить 1с и чтобы командное окно после запуска закрылось и чтобы окно 1с было активно. Так как 1с запускалось автоматически на помощниках покупателя в торговом зале.

Вот рабочий код батника:

```
echo off
chcp 1251
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\8.3.9.2033\bin\1cv8.exe" ^
    ENTERPRISE /S 192.168.0.249\ks /N"Информация о товаре" /DisableStartupMessages
@echo off
echo %time%
timeout 60 > NUL
echo %time%
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
```